# MSSQL: Unknown transaction isolation level

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, websphere, ibatis

I've got some Java code that seems to work fine against DB2/Oracle, but on SQL Server results in a table being locked.

The TXN advice is READ_UNCOMMITTED

```
  <tx:method name="*"
             read-only="false"
             rollback-for="Exception"
             isolation="READ_UNCOMMITTED"/>
```

The websphere default transaction isolation level for the datasource is (webSphereDefaultIsolationLevel) is set to 1 (READ UNCOMMITTED)

But a quartz job is kicked off (that meets the pointcut advice for the tx advice), this then results in the table being locked, as shown in the report below...

so I have two questions...

1: Why is the table locked ? (trying a 'select * OWB_AUDIT' outside the server proves its locked)

2: What does 'Isolation level' of 'Unknown' mean in the report below?

Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Thanks
Jeff

[image: SQL Server Studio Report]

Comment: As it's name implies, **`READ`** `UNCOMMITTED` has no effect on locking behaviour for *write* activities. It certainly appears (from the locks taken) that the transaction in question is making data changes.

Comment: Further to Damien's comment, I believe that any write in the same transaction can bump the whole transaction isolation level up for that transaction.  So check that you are not writing something before the read.

Comment: I can't find any 'write' actions that might be bumping it up. I'll keep digging though. I WILL answer this question! :-)